# Laravel Valet 404 Error

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-valet

I have the following in my `web.php`:

```
Route::resource('/job', 'JobController');
```

Linked to the controller, I have the usual CRUD methods, and some work so for example going to `joben.app/job/1`:

```
public function show(Job $job)
{
    //
    dd($job);
}
```

However, whenever I navigate to `job.app/job` I get a 404 error, and the same whenever I post to `job.app/job`

The code worked fine before and I haven't changed anything, I've attempted reinstalling Valet and also using Artisans own dev server to view and post to the pages and still have the same result

Where can I start looking?

Edit:
Here is my route list for the Job controller (sorry for formatting)

> |        | GET|HEAD  | job                                           | job.index                                  | App\Http\Controllers\JobController@index
> |        | POST      | job                                           | job.store                                  | App\Http\Controllers\JobController@store                                   | web            |
>
> |        | GET|HEAD  | job/create                                    | job.create                                 | App\Http\Controllers\JobController@create                                  | web            |
>
> |        | PUT|PATCH | job/{job}                                     | job.update                                 | App\Http\Controllers\JobController@update                                  | web            |
>
> |        | DELETE    | job/{job}                                     | job.destroy                                | App\Http\Controllers\JobController@destroy                                 | web            |
>
> |        | GET|HEAD  | job/{job}                                     | job.show                                   | App\Http\Controllers\JobController@show                                    | web            |
>
> |        | GET|HEAD  | job/{job}/edit                                | job.edit                                   | App\Http\Controllers\JobController@edit                                    | web            |

and here is the controller code - http://codepad.org/vgot10GN

UPDATE AND SOLUTION:

Ok so this was a pretty unique problem, but it might be happening to you.

I was storing images in public folder - as a test for file uploads under a directory named `job`. Naturally, as the NGINX root for the files is the public folder, when posting to `/job` NGINX first assumed to go to the folder named `job` in the public folder.

Which in this instance was just a folder containing an image.

So after deleting this folder and reattempting it then worked.

Answer (score 2):

When you go to `/job` URL, Laravel will try to execute the `JobController@index` method.

To understand what exactly routes `Route::resource` generates, run this command:

```
php artisan route:list
```

Comment: @iLC please show the `recruiter` middleware. Also, if any other middleware is applied to the route, please show it as well.

Comment: `     public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (\Auth::user()->role->name != 'recruiter') {
            return redirect('profile');
        }

        return $next($request);
    } `

Comment: @iLC do you apply any other middleware to the route in your `web.php`? Please show results for `php artisan route:list` for the `/job` URI.

Comment: added it in the question - i have no other middleware in the `web.php`

Comment: @iLC the code looks fine including the controller, routes etc. Maybe you use cache or something?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your `job.app` is accessible, and if so, your pseudostatic is not configured. Please provide your server is apache or nginx.

Comment: yeah i can navigate to other pages and even some methods in the job controller, just not the index or the store http://codepad.org/vgot10GN